# How to smooth stock data by pandas elegantly?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to smooth the stock data. which ignore the day price gap in the openning, make the price curve smooth in the whole period

Let me list an example:

```
[5]: df = pd.DataFrame([['20190101',2], ['20190101', 3], ['20190102',5], ['20190102', 4], ['20190103', 3], ['20190103', 2]], columns=['date', 'pric
   ...: e'])

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
       date  price
0  20190101      2
1  20190101      3
2  20190102      5
3  20190102      4
4  20190103      3
5  20190103      2
```

above is a stock price dataframe, what i want is to ignore the price gap during day open.

that means the price difference between last one in 20190101 (3) and first one in 20190102(5), 3-5 = -2 is what i want to ignore.

my ignore method is to minus the difference between today and yesterday, which means the expected data should be:

```
 [8]: df
Out[8]: 
       date  price
0  20190101      3
1  20190101      3
2  20190102      3
3  20190102      2
4  20190103      2
5  20190103      1
```

the data in 20190102 is original data(5, 4) - 2(the difference between today and yesterday), so it's 3, 2

is there any good methods can do this?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[20190101,20190101,20190102,20190102,20190103,20190103],'price':[2,3,5,4,3,2]})
df2 = pd.concat([df,df.shift()],axis=1)
df2.columns = ['date','price','date_1','price_1']
df2 = df2[df2.date!=df2.date_1]
df2 = df2.price-df2.price_1
df['adjustedprice'] = df.price.sub(df2,fill_value=0).astype(int)
```

The first commented line is the dataframe itself, uncomment if needed.

What we are doing here is creating an auxiliar dataframe `df2`, with a single day offset. With this single day offset we can calculate day differences and detect day changes. We have done both. First we filtered only the first event of the day (with `df2 = df2[df2.date!=df2.date_1]` and then we took the difference with `df2.price-df2.price_1`, then we subtracted those values already filtered for only the first price of the day to the original values.